# How to determine a projected (if 3D) aspect ratio (if set) of a figure in Matlab to specify a proper paper size?

Tags: matlab, automation, figure, aspect-ratio

I saw many Q&A here about squeezing space out of Matlab figures. However I want to squeeze space resulted from a possibly fixed aspect, i.e. to choose proper paper size for figure printing when aspect is fixed.

Quite often I work with DEM/map/image thus I use `axis image`. Now if I want to produce a high resolution image I do something like

```
set(gcf,'PaperUnits','inches','PaperPosition',[0 0 4 3])
print('-dpng','-r300','somefile.png')
```

as described in [Matlab KB](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-16WME/?solution=1-16WME).

The problem here is to determine a proper aspect such that I can specify proper paper size that would leave no white/background stripes on either sides.

Apparently if I have a map (let's say 1000x2000 cells) with aspect ratio of 0.5, and I'm printing it on 4"x3" paper, I'll get background stripes on the sides. This is quite annoying as I'd prefer 1.5"x3" paper + axes & labels or so. Right now I have to manually adjust paper size.

This is inconvenient as I'd like a universal solution. For instance I may print a plot into file that I expect to occupy 4"x3" as well that has **no** fixed aspect. Or I may want to print a 3D figure. I'm aware of daspect and pbaspect, but how can I know how it is currently drawn?

Perhaps I can derive current 2D aspect from `get(gca,'Position')` and then scale it to my maximum allowed desired size (e.g., 4"x3") while respecting whether *DataAspectRatioMode* (?) property is set to *manual*. Is it the way to proceed or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if I understand your problem exactly, but I have used the following commands to create pdf images that are sized exactly to the size of the figure. I have used this for both 2D and 3D figures. The "handle" variable is simply your figure handle.

```
set(handle,'Units','inches');
set(handle,'PaperUnits','Inches','PaperPositionMode','auto');
P = get(handle,'Position');
set(handle,'PaperSize', [P(3),P(4)]);
```